# Boot failure on MacBook Pro late 2011

Tags: boot, macbook

I have a MacBook Pro late 2011. It displays error code `0xc0000255` on startup. If I hold down the <kbd>Option</kbd> key on startup, it displays 3 devices: the main disk volume, the recovery volume, and another EFI disk).

If I then attempt to boot the main volume, this shows the apple logo and the startup progress bar. It progresses to about half-way and the screen greys out and nothing further happens. Trying the Recovery volume yields the same result. Trying the unnamed EFI disk produced the original error.

I then tried to boot in single-user mode after selecting the main volume. This works! I also tried to boot the system using USB. It also shows the apple logo and progress bar and then fails in the same place. The USB startup was created from a different machine and works fine.

I then used a Windows 10 startup USB and a different hard drive. This installed fine and most things seemed to work (no Wi-Fi) but ethernet was ok.

I tried to run the recovery from the network (Wi-Fi) it also stops after its initial load (but displays nothing).

I then swapped the MAC hard drives between my two MacBooks. The original machine continued to fail, and the additional one booted fine. I have tried to reset NVRAM, but that had no effect.

How can I find out what's wrong? I have access in single user mode. Is there anywhere I can look to find out what is causing this problem?

Comment: Try booting while holding Cmd-V for a verbose boot, and see if the boot log messages on screen give you any insight into the boot failure. Otherwise, it sounds likely to be some kind of hardware problem at this point. You might want to see if you can run [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) to diagnose a hardware problem. If that doesn't work, you'll probably need to contact Apple (or an Apple Authorized Service Provider) for diagnosis and repair.

Comment: Hi, I have already tried to run Apple Hardware test, but it fails to start. I have also run fsck  in single user mode and I get the <OK> message. When I start the machine in verbose mode it scrolls quickly through the startup and presents a grey screen. I have looked into system.log and it shows an error

Comment: couldn't alloc class "com_symantec_symevent_kext"

Comment: AND couldn't alloc class "com_symantec_symevent_kext" and BUG in libdispatch client monitored resource vanished before the source cancel handler was invoked AND Enpoint has been activated through legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in(): com.apple.coreRaid

Comment: That Symantec error can't be from a clean install of macOS. It would be interesting to boot a clean copy of macOS in verbose mode and see what the last few log messages before the hang are.

Answer (score 0):

I had previously lent this machine to another guy. I tracked him done and asked if he noticed anything funny before he returned it to me. Under pressure he admitted that the screen when went "crazy" (all pixellated) and then the system shut down. I suspect that the graphics chip has failed - it seems to be a known problem on this particular machine. Thanks all.